# OpenCV Gstreamer pipeline doesn't work on Pi 4 Buster

Tags: opencv, c++, gstreamer

I'm studying about object tracking and detecting in Gazebo Simulation. So, I'm trying to send Simulation video([Gst Plugin](https://github.com/PX4/sitl_gazebo/blob/master/src/gazebo_gst_camera_plugin.cpp)) to Raspberry Pi 4 via ethernet cable over UDP stream. And Pi 4 side, catch video by using Gstreamer pipeline.

I installed OpenCV 4.2.0-pre from source to Raspberry Pi 4. debianBuster comes with some useful GStreamer libraries and plugins. [Following this site](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/) and customized installation with some correction. I succesfully receive video with this command on Pi side:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5600 caps='application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264' ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink fps-update-interval=1000 sync=false
```

Also this code also works well by using gstreamer library:

[Get video udp h264 with gstreamer and opencv](https://gist.github.com/patrickelectric/5dca1cb7cef4ffa7fbb6fb70dd9f9edc#file-video_udp-cpp)

But it's using cv::Mat* pointer and OpenCV functions doesn't allow pointer to use as a function parameter.
So following code which use Opencv and Gstreamer runs without error or problem in Ubuntu.

```
VideoCapture video("udpsrc port=5600 ! application/x-rtp,payload=96,encoding-name=H264 !"
                       "rtpjitterbuffer mode=1 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink emit-signals=true sync=false max-buffers=1 drop=true", CAP_GSTREAMER);


// Exit if video is not opened
if(!video.isOpened())
{
    cout << "Could not read video file" << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

But in Pi side it can't be opened and code exit in if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I was think that problem is related to Raspberry Pi but it wasn't.
Somehow, OpenCV doesn't recognize GStreamer library when building OpenCV with `cmake` and `make`. Also when I use OpenCV in C++ code stack, OpenCV didn't throw exception when it couldn't find gstreamer support.

I added `-D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON` flag when I'm using cmake command. You can find more information at **stackoverflow**:
[Opencv GStreamer pipeline doesn't work on Raspberry Pi 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729921/opencv-gstreamer-pipeline-doesnt-work-on-raspberry-pi-4/59786605#59786605)

Note: Please let me know if it's counted as a duplicated.